# How do I find the Tenant ID of my SharePoint Online Account?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

I am trying to create a simple PHP script that uses oAuth and I seem to require the Tenant ID of my SharePoint Online account.  I'm sure this is something very straight forward, but I can't seem to locate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found [this approach (blog.scoreman.net)](http://blog.scoreman.net/2013/02/create-site-collections-in-sharepoint-online-using-csom/) easier:

> Navigate to https://.sharepoint.com/_layouts/appprincipals.aspx. Identify the row with your registered application and look at the App Identifier column. The unique identifier after the @-sign in the App Identifier is the app realm. Copy the realm (not the whole App Identifier just the last part after the @-sign).

Answer (score 4):

easiest approach which does not require authentication is here.

for SharePoint Online and Office 365 Tenant id is the same as Azure directory id.

```
https://login.windows.net/<tenant-name>.onmicrosoft.com/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

above URL will return JSON for open id connect. Extract guid from `token_endpoint` property. extracted GUID is your Tenant Id(Tenant Id and directory id is same)

Answer (score 3):

You can get the the Tenant ID from the Azure Active Directory admin center. Navigate to https://aad.portal.azure.com/ and the select Azure Active Directory in the left navigation. The Overview page displays the Tenant ID.

[image: Azure Active Directory admin center]

Answer (score 1):

Tenant ID is nothing but **SharePoint Online Site Realm.**

You can get this by having a REST call to the site API.

Follow below steps:

- Make a Get request

  GET https://your_site.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/client.svc

Header: `Authorization: Bearer`

- Get the **Bearer realm** component from the **response header** and save it.

Check the below post for complete step to be followed:

http://spshell.blogspot.in/2015/03/sharepoint-online-o365-oauth.html

Comment: This throws exception 'Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource'